# Entity Framework NoTracking not working

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to run a no tracking query on my entities so that I can update them outside of the context.  However, when the no tracking is not working and I get an exception stating

"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

This exception is thrown by a property which in terms of the database model is a foreign key to a separate table, do I need to somehow set notracking for this separate entity as well?

My code is:

```
    List<EmailQueue> result = null;
            using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {

                var emailQueueQuery = context.EmailQueues;
                emailQueueQuery.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
                result = emailQueueQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking).ToList<EmailQueue>();

            }
            return result;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wild guess is that you have lazy loading turned on?

If you dispose the `ObjectContext`, then lazy loading can't work.